# Integer solutions to a large sparse equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, mixed-integer-programming

How might one find integer solutions to:

$$
\textrm{diag}(x)Ax = Bx
$$

$A$ and $B$ are integer-valued, square, non-invertible, sparse, and large. The values of $x$ should be $0$ or $1$ (ideally; constraint can be relaxed to include all integers). Are there techniques out there besides MIP?

Comment: By any chance is $B$ nonnegative (or nonpositive)?

Comment: $A$ is non-negative, but $B$ can have both positive and negative values

Comment: Well, that's unhelpful.